# Most efficient way to test a 256-bit YMM AVX register element for equal or less than zero

Tags: c++, x86, simd, avx

I'm implementing a particle system using Intel AVX intrinsics. When the Y-position of a particle is less than or equal to zero I want to reset the particle.

The particle system is ordered in a SOA-pattern like this:

```
class ParticleSystem
{
    private:
        float*      mXPosition;
        float*      mYPosition;
        float*      mZPosition;

        .... Rest of code not important for this question
```

My initial approach I had in mind was just to iterate through the mYPosition array and check for the case stated in the beginning. Perhaps some performance improvmentes could be made with this approach?

The question however is if there is any efficient way to implement this
 using the AVX intrinsics?  Thank you!

Comment: If the rest of code takes longer time than your "check <= zero" does, then it is important to this question.

Comment: I have to disagree. If you're posting code that is irrelavent to the question asked it gets downvoted. Code for initialization, vertex buffer mapping and release of resources have nothing to do with this question.

Comment: What does the "reset particle" code look like? If it is simple as well, then you might be able to come up with a vectorized branchless implementation.

Comment: I can't say I understand this, but it sure looks interesting for signum on avx http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmbugs/2012-July/024072.html

Comment: It's pretty straightforward to do this with AVX - it would be useful to know (a) how many particles typically and (b) what fraction of these are likely to have Y position <= 0 ?

Comment: I will have 1000 particles that all originates in origo. They're emitted upwards in a fountain fashion and will all have Y-position <= 0 at one point in time. When that statement is fullfilled, a particles position will be set back to origio and its velocity will be set to its initial velocity saved at initialization. In that way the scene will loop until it gets closed.

@PaulR I would be super grateful if you could post some hints on checking specific elements in an YMM-register for <= 0.  Thanks!

Comment: @SvinSimpe: sure - see example in answer below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the elements which are <= 0 are relatively sparse then one simple approach is to test 8 at a time using AVX and then drop into scalar code when you identify a vector which contains one or more such elements, e.g.:

```
#include <immintrin.h>                                  // AVX intrinsics

const __m256 vk0 = _mm256_setzero_ps();                 // const vector of zeros

for (int i = 0; i + 8 <= n; i += 8)
{
    __m256 vy = _mm256_loadu_ps(&mYPosition[i]);        // load 8 x floats
    __m256 vcmp = _mm256_cmp_ps(vy, vk0, _CMP_LE_OS);   // compare for <= 0
    int mask = _mm256_movemask_ps(vcmp);                // get MS bits from comparison result
    if (mask != 0)                                      // if any bits set
    {                                                   // then we have 1 or more elements <= 0
        for (int k = 0; k < 8; ++k)                     // test each element in vector
        {                                               // using scalar code...
            if ((mask & 1) != 0)
            {
                // found element at index i + k
                // do something with it...
            }
            mask >>= 1;
        }
    }
}
// deal with any remaining elements in case where n is not a multiple of 8
for (int j = i; j < n; ++j)
{
    if (mYPosition[j] <= 0.0f)
    {
        // found element at index j
        // do something with it...
    }
}
```

Of course if the matching elements are not sparse, i.e. if you are typically finding one or more in every vector of 8, then this isn't going to buy you any performance gain. However if the elements are sparse, such that most vectors can be skipped, then you should see a significant benefit.